# What is a Game Engine?

Tags: terminology

I am new to Game Development, All I have developed is some `2d` Games, using `Game Maker` by [*YoYo Games*](https://www.yoyogames.com/). There game development is much more easy, just as simple as Drag and Drop.

But, Now I wish to evolve in Game Development, and wanna try some hands with the common programming languages like, `Java`, `C++` or `C`. In order to achieve this, I came around the first topic, **`Game Engine`**.

### So, **What is Game Engine.?**

That is a broad question, with various answers. I came out with some conclusion after reading various links,

> **Wikipedia:**
>
> A game engine is a system designed for the creation and development of video games. The core functionality typically provided by a game engine includes a rendering engine for 2D or 3D graphics, a physics engine or collision detection (and collision response), sound, scripting, animation, artificial intelligence, networking, streaming, memory management, threading, localization support, and a scene graph.
>
> [**GameCareerGuide.com**](http://www.gamecareerguide.com/features/529/what_is_a_game_.php?page=1)
>
> It exists to abstract the (sometime platform-dependent) details of doing common game-related tasks, like rendering, physics, and input, so that developers (artists, designers, scripters and, yes, even other programmers) can focus on the details that make their games unique.
>
> Engines offer reusable components that can be manipulated to bring a game to life. Loading, displaying, and animating models, collision detection between objects, physics, input, graphical user interfaces, and even portions of a game's artificial intelligence can all be components that make up the engine.

Now what I understand is, Game Engine takes care of all the common work, like *physics*, *loading* etc...

As far my question is concerned, **what is a Game Engine (Programmatically)?**

Is it a Library? With pre-defined functions and classes, which can be inherited? Or what so ever, what is it?

Comment: it's like the operating system on your computer is the code that does the things behind the walls. instead of running programs it runs the simulation for the game.

Comment: Also: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/10770/whats-the-difference-between-a-library-and-an-engine?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A library simply refers to a collection of classes/functions. There is really not much to it. A Game engine can be released as a library, it's not going to change anything. Afterall software is build from a collection of classes and/or functions.

Where a game engine refers to the basic software of your game. When you speak of a game engine there is at least an architecture involved that handles the bare minimum of the game structure( Entities/Gameobject, rendering, etc ). A lot of the technical stuff is automated for you.

Game engines dictate how certain things are done ( adding scenes, entities/gameobject, loading assets, etc ). All you have to do is add gamelogic and give it an artistic flair ( assets-sound/models/shaders/whatever ).

Game engines exists so that they can boost production. Why or how they do certain things in certain ways is arbitrary ( programming styles as well as work environments can play a big role. To each their own).

Answer (score 2):

Despite many accompanying stuff like editors/tools for the engine it can be 1 of 2 things, I guess:

1. What you said - a kind of library which gives you functions and (code) tools to setup the rendering/window, load assets, manage, update and render them. But it also helps you with audio, physics, AI and so on... The main goal of such a game engine is not to let you do all that - you can do that by youself with raw API - but to let you do it fast and easily.
2. A kind of environment that is closed and let's you only fiddle with some of it's functionality - setup the rendering machine and load/manage the assets. But the core functionality would be the same, I guess.

The difference betweend the two is that in the former case you have either the engine's source code or compiled binaries and use it like a library and in the latter it's a closed unit that you have no access to (like Unity3D) and it only let you do stuff in its editor and with scripts.

But I might be horribly wrong as I've only really worked with 1 commercial engine (Unity3D) and other than that I've tried creating my own ones, to no great effect. Still, I hope it helps.